# Associate VSCode theme with language scopes

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I've made a new color theme in VSCode, very happy with it too. I just followed the instructions using yo code and created a new theme from existing and followed the process.

My new theme is now there in extensions and selectable from the 'color theme' menu which is great but I've noticed a bit if a killer issue. When my theme is selected there is no syntax highlighting for any of the languages I use ( python, javascript, powershell, go, html and so on ). All the text in the editor is plain dark grey. I don't think I changed anything in the theme to change syntax highlighting (to my knowledge).

How can I get syntax highlighting back? Weird because intellisense and code completion (for each language) is still working fine.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Could you share some code to see if maybe something got overridden?